# The simple way to get original relative/global position from expanded FastAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

I use FastAdapter for RecyclerView, let say originally it is like this (all items are collapsed, so only the first level items are showed):

- Africa
- Asia
- Europe

When user expands position 1 it becomes:

- Africa
- Asia

  - Afghanistan
  - Burma
- Europe

How do I get the 2nd position (Europe) when they are expanded like this? Using `getItem(2)` gives Afghanistan. Of course I can count manually because first level and second level uses different `type` in my case, but I am asking about the simplest way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to have a `identifier` per root element, and you then always access the element using that `identifier` this will eliminate the need of checking yourself where you find it.

```
public int getPosition(long identifier)
```

[FastAdapter.getPosition](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter/blob/develop/library-core/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.java#L688)

You can also use the method by passing in your `item` (it needs an `Identifier`)